# Opencart -  round() Function 

Tags: php, opencart, rounding

I have code `<?php echo $product['price']+$product['price']*14/100; ?>` for showing price with TAX in opencart admin (catalog/product).

But I must get price to full number.

For example I have price "298.9992" but I must have "299" etc.

Can you help me?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use round without the second parameter or use 0 as value.

Exemple:

```
round(298.9992);
round(298.9992,0);
```

For more informations:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
round($product, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

to round up your price.

See [the round() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) for more information.

Comment: I had answer by TOM (<?php echo round( $product['price']+$product['price']*14/100); ?>) works great! I have czech eshop and i must have round up/down by math, etc...